# Как сгенерировать xpriv, xpub ключи и адреса btc c#

Tags: c#, bitcoin

Где-то неделю назад начал изучать c# и столкнулся с задачей по генерации bip39 из мнемонической фразы.
Не могу найти подходящий материал, который бы мне помог сгенерировать xpriv, xpub ключи и адреса btc из мнемонической фразы. 
В гугле при поиске "bip39 c#" выдаётся несколько github репозиториев, но при попытке вывода полученного значения у меня программа просто виснет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать библиотеку [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin):

```
using NBitcoin;

...

// генерируем мнемоник (можно также использовать уже существующую строку слов)
var mnemonic = new Mnemonic(Wordlist.English, WordCount.Twelve);

// получаем xprv ключ
var extPrvKey = mnemonic.DeriveExtKey();
// получаем xpub ключ
var extPubKey = extPrvKey.Neuter();

var btcAddress = extPubKey.PubKey.ToString(Network.Main);
var btcScriptAddress = extPubKey.ScriptPubKey.GetScriptAddress(Network.Main);
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nbd1b8 http://prntscr.com/nbd1hh Работает! Только не выводит приватный и публичный ключи.. Так же, хотел бы узнать как можно получить второй адрес, третий и т.д.

Comment: @VladislavSokolov вывести можно так: `extPrvKey.ToString(Network.Main)` - нужно указывать `Network`, т.к. в зависимости от него будет разный результат. А получить второй, третий и т.д. можно вот так: `extPrvKey.Derive(n);`, где `n` - нужный индекс.

Comment: я пытаюсь получить адрес с таким индексом m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 указываю extPubKey.Derive(44).Derive(0).Derive(0).Derive(0).Derive(0).PubKey.GetAddress(Network.Main) . Но результаты в моей программе и на сайте https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ отличаются. Результат в моей программе: 1DGrFcsHCKA7MyFoLX9jzz7dXXD5QX4PRe результат на сайте 1FZeoV87XCeY1ZhNy5nky2inqReu22n89f . Мнемоническая фраза: avocado source payment hobby assume claim roof intact trick flip high vast

Comment: Почитайте спецификацию BIP44 https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#path-levels. Если после индекса стоит `'`, значит используется `hardened derivation`. Т.е. попробуйте так: `extPrvKey.Derive(44, true).Derive(0, true).Derive(0, true).Derive(0).Derive(0).Neuter().PubKey.GetAddress(Network.Main);`

Comment: Вы также можете распарсить строку с путем: `extPrvKey.Derive(KeyPath.Parse("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0")).Neuter().PubKey.GetAddress(Network.Main);`

Comment: Вы лучший! Спасибо!

Comment: можно ли как нибудь задать длину ключей?